# Does vim load /etc/vimrc after ~/.vimrc?

Tags: vim

From `:h initialization`, it seems to say in step 3:

> b. For Unix, MS-DOS, MS-Windows, OS/2, VMS, Macintosh, RISC-OS and Amiga,    the system vimrc file is read for initializations...
>
> c. Four places are searched for initializations... "$HOME/.vimrc"      (for Unix and OS/2)

that `/etc/vimrc` is loaded ahead of `~/.vimrc`.

However, when I added:

```
set textwidth=0
```

in my `~/.vimrc`, I see via `:verbose set textwidth?` that it is still set by `/etc/vimrc` after launching vim. If I then explicitly `:source ~/.vimrc`, `textwidth` is then shown to be set by `~/.vimrc`.

Doesn't this seem to indicate that system vimrc gets loaded after user vimrc (which doesn't seem to make sense)?

FWIW, `:scriptnames` does list `~/.vimrc` after `/etc/vimrc` (which is the first item listed), although I'm not entirely sure the order reflects the start-up loading order of vim.

Comment: System vimrc is loaded before user vimrc.  `:scriptnames` does reflect the order the files are sourced.  `:verbose set ...` shows the last place an option was set.

Comment: That would make more sense, but any idea why `textwidth` in user vimrc doesn't overwrite the one in system vimrc?